# how can I make jenkins find 2 jenkinsfile in a repo with multibranch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am quite new to DevOps and Jenkins in particular. I have played around and created some pipelines jobs. I wanted now to start practicing with a jenkins in local, and apply CI-CD to an small project I had. I have created a multibranch pipeline. which will have 3 repos (front, back, integration). The first 2 repos have 2 jenkinsfile each in the root folder (Jenkinsfile.ci and Jenkinsfile.cd) but when I scan the multibranch pipeline it says no Jenkinsfile has been found. How would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Try running ls after the git checkout to see what files is there. And if Jenkisfile really isnt there.

Comment: What is your reasoning for having two separate Jenkinsfiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your multibranch pipeline build configuration to use **Jenkinsfile.ci** and **Jenkinsfile.cd** instead of **Jenkinsfile**. And you would have to create two multibranch pipelines, one for Jenkinsfile.ci and other for running Jenkinsfile.cd.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so I would then create one MB pipeline for the ```Jenkinsfile.ci ```(both front and back) and another MB pipeline for the ```Jenkinsfile.cd``` (front and back) is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how you should proceed.

Comment: Have you actually been able to make it working like this @jesusfernandez?
AFAIK, multiple Jenkinsfiles are still not being supported by Jenkins multibranch pipelines.
Would be interested, if you found a workaround.